# Install Lubuntu on IdeaPad A1_07

Tags: lenovo, ideapad

Can the latest version of Lubuntu be installed on my Lenovo IdeaPad A1_07?
Thanks.

Comment: Visiting https://lubuntu.me/downloads/ shows x86 & x86_64 downloads available for Lubuntu.  However the IdeaPad A1_07 will run/boot neither as it's an ARMv7 processor (Cortex-A8) akin to a raspberry pi.  Pi or ARMv7 builds exist in Lubuntu for older versions, but not Lubuntu 18.10 (the latest, being 2018-October release).

Comment: @karel I disagree it's a duplicate. It's about PC (x86/x86_64), not more esoteric architectures such as ARM or devices with locked bootloaders. *Trying* on such platforms is not as simple as on a generic PC, and a novice user will generally need quite a lot of instructions for how to boot a custom OS on such platforms, as they are often adapted towards booting a single image.

Answer (score 0):

Visiting https://lubuntu.me/downloads/ shows x86 & x86_64 downloads available for the *latest* Lubuntu (being the 2018-October release; *alternate images exist for the lastest-LTS but I'm taking your latest as meaning 18.10 as altnerates won't help you much either*).

Your IdeaPad A1_07 however will run/boot neither, being a ARMv7 processor (Cortex-A8) akin to a raspberry pi.

Pi or ARMv7 builds exist in Lubuntu for older releases, but not Lubuntu 18.10 (the latest), though it would probably involve a *lot* of work to get a raspberry.pi version to boot on your system, let alone use all your device features (*be what you expect*).